# How can i change this trigger to include all fields in my table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have two tables in a SQL Server:

- Person
- PersonHistory

Everytime someone updates the `Person` table I run this trigger to store a record in the `PersonHistory` table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [TU_Person]
ON [Person]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT
INTO    [PersonHistory]
        ([Field1], [Field2],[Field3],[Field4],[Field5],[Field6], [LastUpdated], [LastUpdatedBy])
SELECT [Field1], [Field2],[Field3],[Field4],[Field5],[Field6], [LastUpdated], [LastUpdatedBy]
FROM    deleted
```

The issue is that I keep adding fields to this table and forget to add the fields to this trigger.  Is there anyway to rewrite this trigger to simply say `insert *` and `Select *` instead of listing out all of the field names one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT
    INTO    [PersonHistory]
    SELECT  * FROM    deleted

This will work if the columns are in an identical order

Additional fields could be added at the beginning or end by altering the select stately to include a date field, for example:

```
INSERT
INTO    [PersonHistory]
SELECT *, getdate() FROM deleted
```

The bigger, more dangerous risk here is that an update will be made to one table and not the other, potentially causing this trigger to error.  This would be a greater evil than a missing field in a live environment - in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT 
INTO [PersonHistory]
SELECT
*
FROM 
deleted
WHERE
inserted.[Common_Field]=deleted.[Common_Field]
```

But it is always advisable to explicitly mention the field names.